# What does "a rock saw of something" mean?

Tags: dialogue, what-women-want

In the movie *What Women Want* I came across the expression "**a rock saw of** shooting beer commercials".

Here's some context from the movie:

> While we’ve been getting **a rock saw of** shooting beer commercials with
> the Swedish bikini team, the industry’s been transformed. We were the
> agency in town ten years ago. Now we’re struggling to be third. If we
> don’t evolve and think beyond our natural ability, we’re gonna go
> down.

What is the meaning of the expression **"a rock saw of..."**?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen), not the actual movie dialogue.

Comment: I downloaded the script and the srt file, and it says _rock saw_ in there.

Comment: You downloaded **a** “script”, obviously transcribed by a human or maybe an AI. That’s different from **the** script, as in what was actually written and read from to make the movie.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Okay, then why in **the** script it says _"She won that **Cleo** last year..."_, whereas in reality it is [**Clio** Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clio_Awards)?

Comment: Because what you downloaded is wrong? That’s what I’m trying to say - you downloaded something that is incorrect and can’t be trusted

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm talking about the continuity script provided in the answer below.

Comment: Are you saying that because there’s a mistake in one script it makes a different script more valid? That doesn’t make sense. Both scripts can have mistakes. The script that you downloaded is wrong. It doesn’t matter what any other script says, that can’t make your script correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [continuity script](https://www.awesomefilm.com/script/whatwomenwant.html) has the correct wording.

> **DAN O.S.:** *My mistake. While we've been **getting our rocks off**...shooting beer commercials with the Swedish bikini team... the industry's been transformed. We were *thee* agency in town ten years ago, now we're struggling to be third.*

Probably in the second sense of the wording, rather than the literal first.

> informal
>
> 1 - (of a man) : to have an orgasm
> 2 - to feel great pleasure or satisfaction
>
> <sub><sup>[Merriam Webster - Idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20one%27s%20rocks%20off#:%7E:text=1,rocks%20off%20bossing%20everyone%20around.)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yeah, assumed it was an eggcorn, or poor transliteration.